# facebook iframe like button not showing up in FF, fine in IE and Chrome

Tags: firefox, facebook-like, facebook-iframe

The below code works fine in IE and Chrome. The src works fine in FF browser. But when I include the code in FF inside a div tag it does not show up

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true" />
```

Comment: I've just edited your code a little.. try this..